# Unable to train a custom objector detector

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, google-colaboratory, training-data, object-detection-api

I'm trying to train my own custom object detector. I have the tf records of both test and train and also label_map.tbtxt. there are a lot of issues with each step.

Comment: can you elaborate more on the issues you are facing ?

Comment: sure. so i ran the train.py file to train a custom object detector of 20 images in training and 5 in test and used Faster Rcnn model. On Google Colab the ram is taking a heavy load according to the picture. can we do anything about it.

Comment: in faster rcnn config, you can set the image dimensions, and reduce the batch size